# Cannot install laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer using composer in laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I try to install laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer using composer in laravel I am getting the following error.

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/symfony/yaml%2416b039275f33279a40460dce5f1109ae4fb02bdf70da7ecdcabefb100b7f6a14.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)
```

Please help.

Comment: did you use this? `composer require laracasts/utilities` and what version of laravel you are using

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja I have used composer require laracasts/utilities:~2.0. My laravel version is 5.

Comment: did you try a lower version?